# Scheduled Media Streaming

Tags: apache-flex, video, adobe, red5, flash-media-server

I have a video that needs to be delivered through streaming, but all viewers need to be synchronized at the same time regardless of when they started the video. If the video starts streaming at 7:00 and someone visits the page at 7:05, they should see the footage at 7:05 and onwards.

Does Red5 or Flash Media Server or any other streaming server have a feature to handle this? or is this something that needs to be handled by the player?

Comment: I would imagine you would handle this on the server based on when the user starts the stream, you'll jump them to the specific point.  But, I don't know specifics on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

regardless of how you load an active stream in Flash, it will start at the beginning of the file stream. For real-time streams that is the moment the user joins the stream since the file stream starts at that moment.